# What is the correct (spec-wise) behavior of "yield* undefined" & "yield undefined" in ES6?

Tags: yield, ecmascript-6, babeljs, traceur

While trying to understand how to work with KoaJS, I came to realize that `yield* undefined` behaves differently between babel & traceur. Babel seem to ignore the statement, while traceur throws an exception.
A sample can be seen here: [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function*%20gen()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log('will%20%5C'yield%201%5C'')%3B%0A%20%20yield%201%3B%0A%20%20console.log('will%20%5C'yield%20undefined%5C'')%3B%0A%20%20yield%20undefined%3B%0A%20%20console.log('will%20%5C'yield*%20undefined%5C'')%3B%0A%20%20yield*%20undefined%3B%0A%20%20console.log('will%20%5C'yield%202%5C'')%3B%0A%20%20yield%202%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F*let%20y%20%3D%20gen()%3B%0Awhile(true)%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20r%20%3D%20y.next()%3B%0A%20%20console.log(JSON.stringify(r))%3B%0A%20%20if(r.done)%0A%20%20%20%20break%3B%0A%7D*%2F%0A%0Alet%20y%20%3D%20gen()%3B%0Awhile(true)%20%7B%0A%20%20try%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20r%20%3D%20y.next()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(JSON.stringify(r))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if(r.done)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20break%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20catch(e)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(e)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log()%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D) - [Traceur](http://www.es6fiddle.net/ia9j3zut/), or below:

```js
function* gen() {
  console.log('will \'yield 1\'');
  yield 1;
  console.log('will \'yield undefined\'');
  yield undefined;
  console.log('will \'yield* undefined\'');
  yield* undefined;
  console.log('will \'yield 2\'');
  yield 2;
}

let y = gen();
while(true) {
  try {
    let r = y.next();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
    if(r.done)
      break;
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log();
    console.log(e);
    console.log();
  };
}
```

I tried looking it up in the [spec](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-generator-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation) and only got more confusion, since the spec for `yield` doesn't look like `yield undefined` is supposed to return with `{done: false}` (No value property), yet that's what happens in both transpilers (also in the sample above). As for `yield*`, I didn't find an answer why traceur should throw. I didn't try this with v8 (node/iojs) yet.

So the question is, what is the correct / expected behavior in both scenarios?

Comment: I've added a [bug report](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1648) about this issue to babel JS

Comment: WTH did this get four downvotes?

Comment: @Bergi - That's what I asked over at Meta earlier, that got me the 4th :-) (It's a bit of an old question if you'd notice)

Comment: Ah, right, didn't notice. You [did ask at meta?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3887516/amit?tab=topactivity)

Comment: @Bergi Yeah... after some useful comment (such as adding the snippet, adding the link to the bug report), and a bit of a bashing, coupled with more downvotes over there (-2), I deleted that one over there and I think I'm done asking questions :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the spec you reference, in the case of `yield* expression`, `expression` [needs to have a `@@iterator` property](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-getiterator), which needs to be a method; otherwise an exception is thrown. Therefore, `yield* undefined` should throw an exception because `undefined` does not have the `@@iterator` property.

In the case of `yield undefined`, `undefined` should be yielded. This is also what happens. However, in your example you evaluate `JSON.stringify({value: undefined, done: false})`, which returns `'{"done": false}'` because there is no such thing as `undefined` in JSON.

Comment: Exactly. So, if you run this in Chrome and Firefox with the appropriate flags currently you'll get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined` and `TypeError: undefined has no properties` respectively.

Comment: Sweet. Bug report it is then :-)